# Zend framework dojo select dojo.byid exception Object #<HTMLTableElement> has no method 'attr'

Tags: zend-framework, dojo, zend-form

I'm trying to get the selected value of my select.
The select element is renderd by Zend Framework Forms I set the attribute 
**'data-dojo-type' to'dijit/form/Select'**
and try to access it with:

```
 require(["dojo/ready"], function(ready){
  ready(function(){
    ServerID = dojo.byId('ElementID').attr('value');
  });
});
```

Chrome keeps tellinge me:

```
Uncaught TypeError: Object #<HTMLTableElement> has no method 'attr'
```

Greetings clemo.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think this should be

```
ServerID = dojo.attr('ElementID', 'value');
```